# Remove a BarButtonItem from NavigationItem

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I am creating an app in which I am using navigation Controller. I had done with adding and removing UIBarButtonItem from the navigation Bar. I have back button at my left side and a additional button at right side named (MORE).

Now my requirement is when I click on the MORE I need to add a CLOSE button on the left side of Navigation Bar and Back button should be hide. I am done with this too.

The problem is while removing the CLOSE button I am using like:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```

It removes my back button too. I need to keep back button and only want to remove the button.

I don't know whether I am right and I need to write code for displaying back button back. or is there any way by which I can remove only CLOSE button on the click of MORE button or CLOSE itself.

Thanks

Comment: Hey friends I got the solution. It solved with the same code I wrote in my post. Iwas looking at wrong side. I don't know should I have to delete it or not when I got my answer but I am keeping this question because if anybody else needed.

Comment: The answer is when I am trying to remove leftbarbuttonItem doesn't mean to remove backButtonItem. Its different. Thanks and sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you tap on MORE button, then BACK button should be hide and MORE should be added on left side of NavBar so you can do this as:

```
-(void) moreButtonClicked{

[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:NO];
UIBarButtonItem *closeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"CLOSE" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector (closeButtonClicked:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = closeButton;
[closeButton release];

}
```

when you want to remove your CLOSE button and set your BACK button at previous place then try this as:

```
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:NO];
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"BACK" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector (backButtonClicked:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
[backButton release];
```

Comment: This is right too... But I was talking about the navigationItem.backBarButtonItem. Any way thanks for reply.